# How to check if ALE found a compile_commands.json file?

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-plugin, vim-ale

I am using neovim with the ALE plugin for linting.

I would like to set the `g:ale_c_cc_options` variable differently depending on if ALE finds a `compile_commands.json` file to use. If it does find the file, I'd like it to run `g:ale_c_cc_options = ''`, that way it only uses the flags defined in the file. Then, if it cannot find the file, I'd like it to use `g:ale_c_cc_option = '-ansi -pedantic -Wall'` as a default option.

Is there anyway to check if ALE succeeds in finding a `compile_commands.json` file, using vimscript?

Something akin to this, possibly?

```
if g:ale_found_compile_commands_file
    let g:ale_c_cc_options = ''
else
    let g:ale_c_cc_options = '-ansi -pedantic -Wall'
endif
```

I'd checked the `:help ale-c-options` manual page, and it had mentioned `g:ale_c_parse_compile_commands`, to enable trying to find a `compile_commands.json` file, but I didn't see any way to check if it succeeds or not?

Comment: @Friedrich Hi, thank you, I didn't know that, my apologies! I can do that rn thanks! After adding a solution, should i remove the edit from the question?

Comment: Another thing (two, actually): I took the liberty of changing the question's title. Feel free to change back or improve. And (completely unrelated), wasn't GCC's `-pedantic` flag deprecated in favor of `-Wpedantic`?

Comment: @Friedrich You're probably right bout it being depreciated, though I haven't seen much use of `-Wpedantic`, in my experience a solid 9/10 times I've see people using `-pedantic`. I think the two are identical though, but if we are being pedantic about things, it should probably be `-Wpedantic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Went through the source code for ALE, found that they were using the `ale#c#FindCompileCommands` function to to get the `compile_commands.json` file. The function returns `['','']` if it cannot find the file, so if we check the return we can tell if ALE found the file or not.

An example implementation using the function may look similar to this

```
function s:apply_cc_options (buffer)
    let [l:root, l:json_file] = ale#c#FindCompileCommands(a:buffer)

    if l:json_file==''
        let g:ale_c_cc_options = '-ansi -pedantic -Wall'
    else
        let g:ale_c_cc_options = ''
    endif

endfunction

autocmd BufReadPost * call s:apply_cc_options(bufnr(''))
```